# Inward looking panorama

Tags: textures, rendering, 3d-modeling

I have a 3d model with very complex geometry. I want to bake these details into a texture map. I want to transfer the rendered image of the model to a low poly version. It is like a panorama, but the camera looks in instead of out. Like a film strip circling an object exposed inward. I will use this image as a texture map. Can this be done? How would you bake geometry and lighting into a texture for a low poly mesh? I am using Keyshot 10, Rhinoceros, Zbrush, and anything free, but I am open to new licenses.

Comment: I don't think that what you are trying to do is going to work. I think what you actually need is support for "Imposters" in your rendering engine. The ability to replace a complex 3d object with a single 2d sprite rendered from roughly the correct angle.

Comment: I'd agree that imposters are the best general-purpose solution here. There might be more specialized options possible that exploit some structure or pattern of your mesh, but without seeing more about the object you're trying to reduce this way, it's hard to speculate what techniques might work well for that case.

Comment: I would like to make a dress for a character and need to turn the fabric details into a texture map